# createCommand() function in yii2 returning false value

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I've made a function 'UpdateSysAcc()' to update a db table's row in yii2 model as:

profile.php

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use app\models\Location;

class Profile extends ActiveRecord {

    public $Fname;
    public $Lname;
    public $Password;
    public $Mail;
    public $Mobile;

public static function db() {
        $db = new \yii\db\Connection([
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ]);
        return $db;
    }

public function UpdateSysAcc($model) {

        echo $this->db()->createCommand("UPDATE `cms_profile` SET `UserName`='$model->Fname $model->Lname',`Mobile1`=$model->Mobile,`Mail`='$model->Mail',`ProfileImg`='db.jpg' WHERE `Mail`='$this->Mail'")->execute();        
    }
}
```

controller file for the above model is:

ProfileController.php

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Profile;
use app\models\Location;

class ProfileController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {
        $model = new Profile;
        $obj = new Location;

        if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($model->UpdateSysAcc($model)) {
                return $this->render('index', ['model' => $model, 'obj' => $obj]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('index', ['model' => $model, 'obj' => $obj]);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

now the problem with above code is that the UPDATE QUERY in UpdateSysAcc() model function successfully updating table data but createCommand() returning false value.

can anybody help me in this case what is the problem with this code?

database schema for the db table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cms_profile` (
`Id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `SysUniqueId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Dob` date NOT NULL,
  `LastActivity` datetime NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Mobile1` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Mobile2` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Mail` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ProfileImg` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `DrName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `DrMobile` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Use concat from PHP end or mysql end for the username, here is mysql way `UserName= concat('$model->Fname,' ', '$model->Lname')`

Comment: `$this->db()->createCommand("UPDATE `cms_systemregister` SET `Fname`='$model->Fname', `Lname`='$model->Lname', `Mobile`=$model->Mobile, `Mail`='$model->Mail', `password`='$model->Password' WHERE `Mail`='$this->Mail'")->execute();`

@AbhikChakraborty - the same problem happening with this command also ....

what is the mistake i repeating with this createCommand() ?

Comment: Put quotes across mobile if its varchar `Mobile='$model->Mobile'`

Comment: i did so but problem still exist !

Answer (score 2):

Change in `UpdateSysAcc` remove `echo` and add `return`, like that

```
public function UpdateSysAcc($model) {

        return $this->db()->createCommand("UPDATE `cms_profile` SET `UserName`='$model->Fname $model->Lname',`Mobile1`=$model->Mobile,`Mail`='$model->Mail',`ProfileImg`='db.jpg' WHERE `Mail`='$this->Mail'")->execute();        
    }
```

Comment: thanks! @vitalik_74,  but that issue was solved with @AbhikChakraborty's answer. 

now the same problem of returning FALSE is again happening with another query in same `createCommand()` function i.e.

`$this->db()->createCommand("UPDATE cms_systemregister SET Fname='$model->Fname', Lname='$model->Lname', Mobile='$model->Mobile', Mail='$model->Mail', password='$model->Password' WHERE Mail='$this->Mail' ")->execute();`

Comment: You should consider passing a variable as a parameter. example $this->db()->createCommand("UPDATE `cms_profile` SET `UserName`=:UserName,`Mobile1`=:mobile,`Mail`=:mail,`ProfileImg`=:ProfileImg WHERE `Mail`=:mail", [
                ':UserName' => '',
                ':mobile' => '',
                ':mail' => '',
                ':ProfileImg' => ''
            ])->execute();

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = 0;
$argument = 'mmm';
$sql = "begin :result := package_name.function_name(:argument); end;";
        $request = Yii::$app->db
            ->createCommand($sql)
            ->bindParam( ":argument", $argument )
            ->bindParam(':result', $result,\PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT,255)
            ->execute();
echo $result;
```

`Use the oracle function in createCommand`

Answer (score 1):

here I found the answer of above problem statement.

yes, there are some syntactic mistakes i did, but after resolving that, The problem was still exist with `createCommand()` returning `FALSE` value, even execution of the query without any error from SQL side.

now i found the reason of that problem , i.e.

if mysql will return `0 rows affected` as return value even after successful execution of the query than the `createCommand()` function will return value as `FALSE` but if there are some rows affected from query execution,  than `createCommand()` will return value as `TRUE`.

once again thanks to @AbhikChakraborty and @vitalik_74.